# How to mock function which is called twice jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, graphql

I need to write a test case for the function which is called twice inside a function.

```
async getAssets ( skuId, commonSku) {
    const { items } = await this.getMediaSet( skuId ); 
    const { items: commonSkuItems } = commonSku ? await this.getMediaSet( commonSku ) : { items: []}; 
    return [ ...items, ...commonSkuItems ];
 }
```

What `getMediaSet` method is returning is an object of data specific to skuId passed like below

```
  const response =  {

  "items": [
    {
     "type": "img",
     "src": "https://media/25131",
     "width": 2000,
     "height": 2000,
     "format": "PNG",
     "opaque": "false"
   },
   {
    "type": "img",
    "src": "https://media/23232",
    "width": 2000,
    "height": 2000,
    "format": "PNG",
    "opaque": "false"
   }
 ]
}
```

How I am trying to testing is like below

```
  const result =  {

  "items": [
    {
     "type": "img",
     "src": "https://media/25131",
     "width": 2000,
     "height": 2000,
     "format": "PNG",
     "opaque": "false"
   },
   {
    "type": "img",
    "src": "https://media/23232",
    "width": 2000,
    "height": 2000,
    "format": "PNG",
    "opaque": "false"
   }
 ]
}

      const getMediaSet = jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => Promise.resolve( {response} ) );
 
  
  let output = await getAssets( '251', '253' );
  expect( output ).toMatchObject( result );
```

**Issue is how to mock `getMediaSet` `twice` ?** because I getting undefined for its another call.

Answer (score 3):

So, I found its answer. We need to change function mock implementation like this

```
   cmsDataSource.getMediaSet = jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue( response ) // Response in first call
    .mockReturnValueOnce( response ) // Response in second call
```

**Instead of**

```
 const getMediaSet = jest.fn().mockImplementation( () => Promise.resolve( {response} ) );
```

Comment: Side note: it seems that when you put mockReturnValueOnce, it actually takes precedence. So you would either need to use both cases as `mockReturnValueOnce` in order, or the order would be the inverse of the comments you added, at least from my tests. Either way, this was a big help!